# Не работает обработчик нажатия клавиш

Tags: jquery

Навесил обработчик нажатия клавиатуры .on('keydown'), но он не работает, клавишы нажимаются, но ничего не происходит - навигация не работает, модальное окно не исчезает. Что не так в моём коде? Вот код (нужный обработчик выделен):

```
$(function(){
var previews = document.getElementsByClassName('fotoBest'),
    pl = previews.length,
    max = pl - 1,
    album = '',
    imgs = '';
$('.foto').on('click', '.fotoBest', function(e){
    var ipreview = $(this).index();
    album = '<div id="album"><div id="simplePhoto"><div id="control"><div class="arrowleft"><span>&#9001;</span></div><div class="arrowright"><span>&#9002;</span></div></div></div><div id="numberPhoto"></div><div id="close">&times;</div></div>';
    if (!imgs) {
        for (var a=0; b=pl, a<b; a++) {
            var c = a + 1;
            imgs += '<img src="img/b_img/' + c + '.jpg" alt="b' + c + '">';
        }
    }
    $('#lb').append(album);
    $('#simplePhoto').append(imgs);
    var photo = $('#simplePhoto > img'),
        targetPhoto = photo.eq(ipreview);
    photo.first().addClass('imgstart');
    photo.last().addClass('imgend');
    if ($(this).attr('href') === targetPhoto.attr('src')) {
        targetPhoto.addClass('targetimg');
        $('#numberPhoto').text($('.targetimg').index());
    }
    $('#lb').show();
    return false;
});

var targimg = document.getElementsByClassName('targetimg'),
    itargimg = $(targimg).index(),
imageleft = function() {
    if ($(targimg).hasClass('imgstart')) {
        $('.imgend').addClass('targetimg');
        $('.targetimg:first').removeClass('targetimg');
    } else {
        $(targimg).prev('img').addClass('targetimg');
        $('.targetimg:last').removeClass('targetimg');
    }
    $('#numberPhoto').text($('.targetimg').index());
},
imageright = function() {
    if ($(targimg).hasClass('imgend')) {
        $('.imgstart').addClass('targetimg');
        $('.targetimg:last').removeClass('targetimg');
    } else {
        $(targimg).next('img').addClass('targetimg');
        $('.targetimg:first').removeClass('targetimg');
    }
    $('#numberPhoto').text($('.targetimg').index());
};

$('#lb').on('click.arrowl', '.arrowleft', function(e){
    imageleft();
    return false;
});
$('#lb').on('click.arrowr', '.arrowright', function(e){
    imageright();
    return false;
});

$('#lb').on('click.timg', '#control', function(e){
    imageright();
    return false;
});

$('#lb').on('click.close', '#close', function(e){
    $('#lb').hide();
    $('#album').remove();
    return false;
});

$('#lb').on('click.hidelb', function(e){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#album').remove();
    return false;
});
$('#lb').on('keydown', function(e){ //тут
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        imageleft();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        imageright();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#album').remove();
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: @CMargl, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: зачем вам позвольте узнать document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: делайте jsfiddle.

Comment: Мелкая оптимизация. Про jsfiddle в курсе, просто ещё им не пользовался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){ //тут
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        imageleft();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        imageright();
    } else if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#album').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо, Олег Б